# Constraint-based unit testing framework for Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is there a constraint-based unit testing framework for CPython (much like my beloved NUnit) or will I have to roll my own?

**EDIT:**

This is what I mean by constraint-based:
http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=constraintModel&r=2.6

i.e. instead of:

```
assert(z.Count > 5)
```

it's more like:

```
assert.that(z.Count, Is.GreaterThan(5))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: there is none. And really, there's no point. It's useful in languages like C#/Java, but not in Python where you can do things like assert(i in [1, 2, 3]).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if such a thing exists for Python unit testing tools, but it seems like something that can be solved quite easily if you have to roll your own, using Python's functional capabilities. For example, let's have a function called assertThat as follows:

```
def assertThat(val, constraint):
    assert(constraint(val))
```

Constraint could be defined this way:

```
def equal(testVal):
    def c(val):
        return testVal == val
```

Then, you can just use it like this:

```
assertThat(myVal, equal(5))
```

which does what you expect it to do.

That's just the start of it; I suspect that with decorators, the operator module and an afternoon off, you could create a pretty comprehensive set of very useful constraint functions!

Comment: Thanks! It seems like I'll have to find a free afternoon and roll my own version. But it should be quite easy with Python's expressiveness. I'm just surprised noone implemented this already.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in library [unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) provides the functionality you seek. You will find the [list of assert methods](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#assert-methods) very useful for making specific assertions.

```
from unittest import TestCase

class SomeTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.value = 5

    def testMyValue(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.value, 5)
```

This is somewhat different to the constraints in NUnit but it is easy to adapt an can be quite powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to check out [testtools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/testtools), which appears to have the syntax you are after.  It makes the tests more readable, and works in Python 2.6+

```
class TestSillySquareServer(TestCase):

    def test_server_is_cool(self):
        self.assertThat(self.server.temperature, Equals("cool"))

    def test_square(self):
        self.assertThat(self.server.silly_square_of(7), Equals(49))
```